# Pass current context to dustjs helper

Tags: dust.js

I'm using a partial helper as;

```
{<subTemplate}
 {type}
 {minute}
 {count}
{/subTemplate}

{@partial type=type minute=minute count=count}
  {+sub_template/}
{/partial}
```

but as you can see for any field I want to use in my subTemplate, I need to add to the partial declaration. I tried

```
{@partial record=.}
  {+sub_template/}
{/partial}
```

but doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation does not state that the base template ever gets access to the the Context. It appears that it is intended for html formatting only. Not for data. See [Dust Blocks and inline partials](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#wiki-blocks-and-inline-partials) for more info.

You could set a global context variable for use in the base template to get around this limitation. This is also described in the dust tutorial at [Setting your own context](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#wiki-setting-your-own-context-before-render).